# specification of function templates

Tags: c++, templates, derived-class, base-class, function-templates

I would like to create a function template where the class T is limited to only derived classes of a special base class T_base. What is the efficient way to accomplish this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use type traits and SFINAE

```
template<typename T, 
         bool[std::is_base_of<T_base, T>::value] = nullptr>
void f(T const&);
```

C++03 version that also works for C++11

```
template<typename T>
typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_base_of<T_base, T> >::type 
f(T const&);
```

There is the C++11 version of moving the `enable_if` into the template parameter list, using a default argument

```
template<typename T, 
         typename = typename std::enable_if<
           std::is_base_of<T_base, T>::value>::type>
void f(T const&);
```

Sadly you then cannot overload `f` if the only difference of your other overload is the SFINAE string (i.e the default argument), because the default argument is not part of the signature of a function template. But the type of the template parameters themselfs are (these rules are just like for normal function parameters).

Comment: Take notice though, that these are C++11 features

Answer (score 1):

C++0x has `std::enable_if`; if your compiler doesn't yet support it, there's `boost::enable_if`.

For example if the signature would be `template<typename T> int f(T&)`, you'd use

```
template<typename T>
  std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T_base, T>::value, int>::type f(T&);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of would be something like this:

```
template<class T>
void someFunc(T arg)
{
    dynamic_cast<BaseClass>(arg); // will throw an exception if not castable to base class
    // continue...
}
```

Comment: Johannes' solution is better ;)